# Invalid binary expression operands for template argument for special string case

Tags: c++

Here is what I wanted to achive.
I need a function that takes `lhs` and `rhs` where `lhs` is always of type `std::string`  and return the string `{rhs} + {lhs}`.
In theory `rhs` can be any type, but the library will only take `std::string` and all types supported by `std::to_string(input)`.

So my idea was to use `std::is_same<T1, T2>::value` to identify if `rhs` is a `std::string`. Using a structure similar to this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> std::string test(std::string lhs, T rhs)
{

    std::string base = lhs + " = "; 
    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        return base + rhs;
    }
    else
    {
        return lhs + " = " + std::to_string(rhs);  
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string a = "12"; 
    int b = 10;

    std::cout << test(a, b) << "\n"; 

    uint8_t c = 253;
    std::cout << test(a, c) << "\n";

    std::string d = "15";
    std::cout << test(a, d) << "\n"; 
}
```

But I get this error when trying to compile:

```
main.cpp:13:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') and 'int')
        return base + rhs;
               ~~~~ ^ ~~~
```

Followed by a gazzilion

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6081:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
```

I compile the code with following compile string `clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`

Comment: Having `const std::string& std::to_string(const std::string&)` would have solved that issue :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `base + rhs;` must be valid even `std::is_same<T, std::string>::value` is `false`; i.e. both statement-false and statement-true need to be valid no matter whether the condition is `true` or `false`.

You need the help of [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) (since C++17). The statement-true or statement-false would be discarded according to the value of condition. E.g.

```
template<typename T> std::string test(std::string lhs, T rhs)
{

    std::string base = lhs + " = "; 
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        return base + rhs;
    }
    else
    {
        return lhs + " = " + std::to_string(rhs);  
    }
}
```

Comment: i am a little confused about the terms "constexpr if" vs "if constexpr". Is one colloquial the other official, or are both just fine?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I get it from cppreference.com, it says "Constexpr If". :)

Comment: yeah they use "Constexpr if" in the header, but not elsewhere. Perhaps I just have to be a little less pedantic, i mean there is no chance of big confusion

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It seems the standard use this term too, like "constexpr if statement".

Comment: oh right, it was not pedantry but just carelessness. Sorry, need more coffee

Comment: BAAHHH of  cause, stupid that I forgot that. Thanks @songyuanyao